# How to move node in VirtualTreeView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, virtualtreeview

I use Delphi XE5 and created a VirtualTree with several parent and child nodes. When I select a child node and execute the following code:

```
vstSource:= vstTree.FocusedNode;
vstTarget:= vstTree.GetNextSibling(vstSource);
vstTree.moveto(vstSource,vstTarget,amInsertAfter,false);
```

The cursor jumps to the next node and selects it but the selected node does not move down.

I use VirtualTreeView v.5.3.0.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

---

**Edit:**

I've made an update to v.6.0 but nothing changes. Here's the full code (it's only a sample to test the VirtualTree):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  myTree.RootNodeCount := 2;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  SNode, TNode: PVirtualNode;
begin
  SNode:= myTree.FocusedNode;
  TNode:= myTree.GetNextSibling(SNode);
  myTree.MoveTo(SNode, TNode, amInsertAfter, False);
end; 

procedure TForm1.myTreeGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType; var CellText: string);
begin
  if Column > 0 then
    Exit;

  case Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node) of
    0: CellText := 'Main';
    1:
    case Node.Index of
      0: CellText := 'Val1';
      1: CellText := 'Val2';
      2: CellText := 'Val3';
      3: CellText := 'Val4';
      4: CellText := 'Val5';
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.myTreeInitNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; ParentNode,
  Node: PVirtualNode; var InitialStates: TVirtualNodeInitStates);
begin
  if Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node) = 0 then
    Sender.ChildCount[Node] := 5;
end;
```

Comment: The code seems to be correct; maybe the error is in another part of the unit. Can you complete the example with more code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in v6.0.0. But anyway, I'd urge you to [update](https://github.com/Virtual-TreeView/Virtual-TreeView/archive/master.zip).